# How do I increase the buffer size of the Cocos2d-js JSB?

Tags: javascript, android, json, cocos2d-js

When I send long JSON data from Android Studio to the cocos layer, it gets truncated. How do I increase the buffer size of the Javascript Bridge (JSB)?

Comment: I don't have a real answer to your question, but, in the meantime: have you thougt of breaking up the JSON in smaller parts?